# UK short term tourist visa cancellation processing time

Tags: visas, uk

I cancelled UK visa (withdraw) same day after applying it as I had made a spelling error in my parent's name (I know stupid mistake)I received an email which said the request has been received, if the decision is made and my request is accepted my credit card will be refunded within 28 days. It has been 4 business days and I have not received the email saying my request accepted. How long does it take has anyone been in same shoes? or have any information on this?